# Google Charts - issue with PHP Array to JS (Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to display charts with Google Charts but somehow part of my arrays are seen as strings and cannot be read by Google Charts.

I'm using the following code to initialize Google Charts:

```
initCharts("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js",displayCharts);   

function initCharts(url, callback)
{
    var head = document.head;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

and then call my function:

```
function displayCharts()
{
    chart_types = ["battery","battery"];
    chart_datas =["[['timing','charge'],['1min',1],['2min',1],['3min',1],['4min',2],['5min',2],['6min',3],['7min',4],['8min',4],['9min',5],['10min',5],['11min',6],['12min',6],['13min',7],['14min',7],['15min',8],['16min',9],['17min',9],['18min',10],['19min',10],['20min',11],['21min',12],['22min',12],['23min',13],['24min',14],['25min',14],['26min',15],['27min',15],['28min',16],['29min',16],['30min',17],['31min',18],['32min',18],['33min',19],['34min',19],['35min',20],['36min',20],['37min',21],['38min',22],['39min',22],['40min',23],['41min',23],['42min',24],['43min',24],['44min',25],['45min',26],['46min',26],['47min',27],['48min',27],['49min',28],['50min',28],['51min',29],['52min',30],['53min',30],['54min',31],['55min',31],['56min',32],['57min',32],['58min',33],['59min',33],['60min',34],['61min',34],['62min',35],['63min',36],['64min',36],['65min',37],['66min',37],['67min',38],['68min',38],['69min',39],['70min',39],['71min',39],['72min',40],['73min',40],['74min',41],['75min',41],['76min',42],['77min',42],['78min',43],['79min',43],['80min',44],['81min',44],['82min',45],['83min',45],['84min',46],['85min',46],['86min',47],['87min',47],['88min',48],['89min',48],['90min',49],['91min',49],['92min',50],['93min',50],['94min',51],['95min',51],['96min',52],['97min',52],['98min',53],['99min',53],['100min',54],['101min',54],['102min',55],['103min',55],['104min',55],['105min',56],['106min',56],['107min',57],['108min',57],['109min',58],['110min',58],['111min',59],['112min',59],['113min',60],['114min',60],['115min',60],['116min',61],['117min',61],['118min',62],['119min',62],['120min',63],['121min',63],['122min',64],['123min',64],['124min',64],['125min',65],['126min',65],['127min',66],['128min',66],['129min',67],['130min',67],['131min',67],['132min',68],['133min',68],['134min',69],['135min',69],['136min',70],['137min',70],['138min',71],['139min',71],['140min',71],['141min',72],['142min',72],['143min',73],['144min',73],['145min',74],['146min',74],['147min',75],['148min',75],['149min',76],['150min',76],['151min',77],['152min',77],['153min',77],['154min',78],['155min',78],['156min',79],['157min',79],['158min',80],['159min',80],['160min',80],['161min',81],['162min',81],['163min',82],['164min',82],['165min',83],['166min',83],['167min',84],['168min',84],['169min',84],['170min',85],['171min',85],['172min',86],['173min',86],['174min',86],['175min',87],['176min',87],['177min',88],['178min',88],['179min',88],['180min',89],['181min',89],['182min',90],['183min',90],['184min',90],['185min',91],['186min',91],['187min',91],['188min',92],['189min',92],['190min',92],['191min',92],['192min',93],['193min',93],['194min',93],['195min',93],['196min',94],['197min',94],['198min',94],['199min',95],['200min',95],['201min',95],['202min',95],['203min',96],['204min',96],['205min',96],['206min',97],['207min',97],['208min',97],['209min',97],['210min',97],['211min',98],['212min',98],['213min',98],['214min',98],['215min',98],['216min',98],['217min',98],['218min',98],['219min',98],['220min',99],['221min',99],['222min',99],['223min',99],['224min',99],['225min',100]]","[['timing','discharge100','discharge50'],['1min',100,98],['2min',100,98],['3min',100,98],['4min',100,98],['5min',100,98],['6min',100,98],['7min',100,98],['8min',100,98],['9min',100,98],['10min',100,97],['11min',100,97],['12min',100,97],['13min',100,97],['14min',100,97],['15min',100,97],['16min',100,97],['17min',100,97],['18min',100,97],['19min',100,96],['20min',100,96],['21min',100,96],['22min',100,96],['23min',100,96],['24min',100,96],['25min',99,96],['26min',99,95],['27min',99,95],['28min',99,95],['29min',99,95],['30min',99,95],['31min',99,95],['32min',98,95],['33min',98,94],['34min',98,94],['35min',98,94],['36min',98,94],['37min',98,94],['38min',98,94],['39min',98,94],['40min',98,94],['41min',97,93],['42min',97,93],['43min',97,93],['44min',97,93],['45min',97,93],['46min',97,93],['47min',97,93],['48min',97,92],['49min',96,92],['50min',96,92],['51min',96,92],['52min',96,92],['53min',96,92],['54min',96,92],['55min',96,91],['56min',96,91],['57min',95,91],['58min',95,91],['59min',95,91],['60min',95,91],['61min',95,91],['62min',95,91],['63min',95,90],['64min',95,90],['65min',94,90],['66min',94,90],['67min',94,90],['68min',94,90],['69min',94,90],['70min',94,89],['71min',94,89],['72min',94,89],['73min',93,89],['74min',93,89],['75min',93,89],['76min',93,89],['77min',93,88],['78min',93,88],['79min',93,88],['80min',92,88],['81min',92,88],['82min',92,88],['83min',92,88],['84min',92,88],['85min',92,87],['86min',92,87],['87min',91,87],['88min',91,87],['89min',91,87],['90min',91,87],['91min',91,87],['92min',91,86],['93min',91,86],['94min',91,86],['95min',90,86],['96min',90,86],['97min',90,86],['98min',90,86],['99min',90,85],['100min',90,85],['101min',90,85],['102min',90,85],['103min',89,85],['104min',89,85],['105min',89,85],['106min',89,84],['107min',89,84],['108min',89,84],['109min',89,84],['110min',88,84],['111min',88,84],['112min',88,84],['113min',88,84],['114min',88,83],['115min',88,83],['116min',88,83],['117min',88,83],['118min',88,83],['119min',88,83],['120min',88,83],['121min',88,82],['122min',88,82],['123min',88,82],['124min',88,82],['125min',87,82],['126min',87,82],['127min',87,82],['128min',87,81],['129min',87,81],['130min',87,81],['131min',87,81],['132min',87,81],['133min',87,81],['134min',87,81],['135min',87,81],['136min',87,81],['137min',87,80],['138min',87,80],['139min',87,80],['140min',87,80],['141min',87,80],['142min',87,80],['143min',87,80],['144min',87,79],['145min',87,79],['146min',87,79],['147min',87,79],['148min',87,79],['149min',86,79],['150min',86,79],['151min',86,78],['152min',86,78],['153min',86,78],['154min',86,78],['155min',86,78],['156min',86,78],['157min',86,78],['158min',86,78],['159min',86,77],['160min',86,77],['161min',86,77],['162min',86,77],['163min',86,77],['164min',86,77],['165min',86,77],['166min',86,76],['167min',86,76],['168min',86,76],['169min',86,76],['170min',86,76],['171min',86,76],['172min',85,76],['173min',85,75],['174min',85,75],['175min',85,75],['176min',85,75],['177min',85,75],['178min',85,75],['179min',85,75],['180min',85,74],['181min',85,74],['182min',85,74],['183min',85,74],['184min',85,74],['185min',85,74],['186min',85,74],['187min',85,74],['188min',85,73],['189min',85,73],['190min',85,73],['191min',85,73],['192min',85,73],['193min',85,73],['194min',85,73],['195min',84,72],['196min',84,72],['197min',84,72],['198min',84,72],['199min',84,72],['200min',84,72],['201min',84,72],['202min',84,71],['203min',84,71],['204min',84,71],['205min',84,71],['206min',84,71],['207min',84,71],['208min',84,71],['209min',84,71],['210min',84,70],['211min',84,70],['212min',84,70],['213min',84,70],['214min',84,70],['215min',84,70],['216min',84,70],['217min',83,69],['218min',83,69],['219min',83,69],['220min',83,69],['221min',83,69],['222min',83,69],['223min',83,69],['224min',83,68],['225min',83,68],['226min',83,68],['227min',83,68],['228min',83,68],['229min',83,68],['230min',83,67],['231min',83,67],['232min',83,67],['233min',83,67],['234min',83,67],['235min',83,67],['236min',83,67],['237min',83,67],['238min',83,66],['239min',82,66],['240min',82,66],['241min',82,66],['242min',82,66],['243min',82,66],['244min',82,66],['245min',82,65],['246min',82,65],['247min',82,65],['248min',82,65],['249min',82,65],['250min',82,65],['251min',82,64],['252min',82,64],['253min',82,64],['254min',82,64],['255min',82,64],['256min',82,64],['257min',82,64],['258min',82,63],['259min',82,63],['260min',82,63],['261min',81,63],['262min',81,63],['263min',81,63],['264min',81,63],['265min',81,63],['266min',81,62],['267min',81,62],['268min',81,62],['269min',81,62],['270min',81,62],['271min',81,62],['272min',81,61],['273min',81,61],['274min',81,61],['275min',81,61],['276min',81,61],['277min',81,61],['278min',81,61],['279min',81,60],['280min',81,60],['281min',80,60],['282min',80,60],['283min',80,60],['284min',80,60],['285min',80,60],['286min',80,59],['287min',80,59],['288min',80,59],['289min',80,59],['290min',80,59],['291min',80,59],['292min',80,58],['293min',80,58],['294min',80,58],['295min',80,58],['296min',80,58],['297min',80,58],['298min',80,57],['299min',80,57],['300min',80,57],['301min',80,57],['302min',80,57],['303min',79,57],['304min',79,57],['305min',79,57],['306min',79,56],['307min',79,56],['308min',79,56],['309min',79,56],['310min',79,56],['311min',79,56],['312min',79,55],['313min',79,55],['314min',79,55],['315min',79,55],['316min',79,55],['317min',79,55],['318min',79,54],['319min',79,54],['320min',79,54],['321min',79,54],['322min',79,54],['323min',79,54],['324min',78,54],['325min',78,53],['326min',78,53],['327min',78,53],['328min',78,53],['329min',78,53],['330min',78,53],['331min',78,53],['332min',78,53],['333min',78,52],['334min',78,52],['335min',78,52],['336min',78,52],['337min',78,52],['338min',78,52],['339min',78,52],['340min',78,51],['341min',78,51],['342min',78,51],['343min',78,51],['344min',78,51],['345min',78,51],['346min',77,51],['347min',77,50],['348min',77,50],['349min',77,50],['350min',77,50],['351min',77,50],['352min',77,50],['353min',77,50],['354min',77,49],['355min',77,49],['356min',77,49],['357min',77,49],['358min',77,49],['359min',77,49],['360min',77,49],['361min',77,49],['362min',77,48],['363min',77,48],['364min',77,48],['365min',77,48],['366min',77,48],['367min',76,48],['368min',76,48],['369min',76,47],['370min',76,47],['371min',76,47],['372min',76,47],['373min',76,47],['374min',76,47],['375min',76,46],['376min',76,46],['377min',76,46],['378min',76,46],['379min',76,46],['380min',76,46],['381min',76,46],['382min',76,46],['383min',76,45],['384min',76,45],['385min',76,45],['386min',76,45],['387min',76,45],['388min',75,45],['389min',75,45],['390min',75,44],['391min',75,44],['392min',75,44],['393min',75,44],['394min',75,44],['395min',75,44],['396min',75,44],['397min',75,43],['398min',75,43],['399min',75,43],['400min',75,43],['401min',75,43],['402min',75,43],['403min',75,43],['404min',75,42],['405min',75,42],['406min',75,42],['407min',75,42],['408min',75,42],['409min',75,42],['410min',74,42],['411min',74,42],['412min',74,41],['413min',74,41],['414min',74,41],['415min',74,41],['416min',74,41],['417min',74,41],['418min',74,40],['419min',74,40],['420min',74,40],['421min',74,40],['422min',74,40],['423min',74,40],['424min',74,40],['425min',74,39],['426min',74,39],['427min',74,39],['428min',74,39],['429min',74,39],['430min',73,39],['431min',73,39],['432min',73,39],['433min',73,38],['434min',73,38],['435min',73,38],['436min',73,38],['437min',73,38],['438min',73,38],['439min',73,38],['440min',73,37],['441min',73,37],['442min',73,37],['443min',73,37],['444min',73,37],['445min',73,37],['446min',73,36],['447min',73,36],['448min',73,36],['449min',73,36],['450min',72,36],['451min',72,36],['452min',72,36],['453min',72,36],['454min',72,35],['455min',72,35],['456min',72,35],['457min',72,35],['458min',72,35],['459min',72,35],['460min',72,34],['461min',72,34],['462min',72,34],['463min',72,34],['464min',72,34],['465min',72,34],['466min',72,34],['467min',72,33],['468min',72,33],['469min',72,33],['470min',72,33],['471min',71,33],['472min',71,33],['473min',71,33],['474min',71,32],['475min',71,32],['476min',71,32],['477min',71,32],['478min',71,32],['479min',71,32],['480min',71,32],['481min',71,31],['482min',71,31],['483min',71,31],['484min',71,31],['485min',71,31],['486min',71,31],['487min',71,31],['488min',71,30],['489min',71,30],['490min',71,30],['491min',71,30],['492min',70,30],['493min',70,30],['494min',70,29],['495min',70,29],['496min',70,29],['497min',70,29],['498min',70,29],['499min',70,29],['500min',70,28],['501min',70,28],['502min',70,28],['503min',70,28],['504min',70,28],['505min',70,28],['506min',70,28],['507min',70,28],['508min',70,27],['509min',70,27],['510min',70,27],['511min',70,27],['512min',70,27],['513min',69,27],['514min',69,26],['515min',69,26],['516min',69,26],['517min',69,26],['518min',69,26],['519min',69,26],['520min',69,25],['521min',69,25],['522min',69,25],['523min',69,25],['524min',69,25],['525min',69,25],['526min',69,24],['527min',69,24],['528min',69,24],['529min',69,24],['530min',69,24],['531min',69,24],['532min',69,24],['533min',69,24],['534min',68,23],['535min',68,23],['536min',68,23],['537min',68,23],['538min',68,23],['539min',68,23],['540min',68,22],['541min',68,22],['542min',68,22],['543min',68,22],['544min',68,22],['545min',68,22],['546min',68,21],['547min',68,21],['548min',68,21],['549min',68,21],['550min',68,21],['551min',68,21],['552min',68,21],['553min',67,20],['554min',67,20],['555min',67,20],['556min',67,20],['557min',67,20],['558min',67,20],['559min',67,19],['560min',67,19],['561min',67,19],['562min',67,19],['563min',67,19],['564min',67,19],['565min',67,18],['566min',67,18],['567min',66,18],['568min',66,18],['569min',66,18],['570min',66,18],['571min',66,17],['572min',66,17],['573min',66,17],['574min',66,17],['575min',66,17],['576min',66,17],['577min',66,16],['578min',66,16],['579min',66,16],['580min',66,16],['581min',66,16],['582min',66,16],['583min',66,16],['584min',66,15],['585min',66,15],['586min',65,15],['587min',65,15],['588min',65,15],['589min',65,14],['590min',65,14],['591min',65,14],['592min',65,14],['593min',65,14],['594min',65,14],['595min',65,13],['596min',65,13],['597min',65,13],['598min',65,13],['599min',65,13],['600min',65,13],['601min',65,12],['602min',65,12],['603min',65,12],['604min',65,12],['605min',64,12],['606min',64,12],['607min',64,11],['608min',64,11],['609min',64,11],['610min',64,11],['611min',63,11],['612min',63,11],['613min',63,10],['614min',63,10],['615min',63,10],['616min',63,10],['617min',62,10],['618min',62,10],['619min',62,10],['620min',62,9],['621min',62,9],['622min',62,9],['623min',61,9],['624min',61,9],['625min',61,9],['626min',61,9],['627min',61,9],['628min',61,8],['629min',61,8],['630min',60,8],['631min',60,8],['632min',60,8],['633min',60,7],['634min',60,7],['635min',60,7],['636min',59,7],['637min',59,7],['638min',59,7],['639min',59,7],['640min',59,6],['641min',59,6],['642min',58,6],['643min',58,6],['644min',58,6],['645min',58,6],['646min',58,5],['647min',58,5],['648min',57,5],['649min',57,5],['650min',57,5],['651min',57,4],['652min',57,4],['653min',57,4],['654min',56,4],['655min',56,3],['656min',56,3],['657min',56,3],['658min',56,3],['659min',56,2],['660min',56,2],['661min',56,2],['662min',55,2],['663min',55,1],['664min',55,0],['665min',55,0],['666min',55,0],['667min',55,0],['668min',54,0],['669min',54,0],['670min',54,0],['671min',54,0],['672min',54,0],['673min',54,0],['674min',54,0],['675min',53,0],['676min',53,0],['677min',53,0],['678min',53,0],['679min',53,0],['680min',53,0],['681min',53,0],['682min',52,0],['683min',52,0],['684min',52,0],['685min',52,0],['686min',52,0],['687min',52,0],['688min',52,0],['689min',51,0],['690min',51,0],['691min',51,0],['692min',51,0],['693min',51,0],['694min',51,0],['695min',51,0],['696min',50,0],['697min',50,0],['698min',50,0],['699min',50,0],['700min',50,0],['701min',50,0],['702min',50,0],['703min',50,0],['704min',49,0],['705min',49,0],['706min',49,0],['707min',49,0],['708min',49,0],['709min',49,0],['710min',49,0],['711min',48,0],['712min',48,0],['713min',48,0],['714min',48,0],['715min',48,0],['716min',48,0],['717min',47,0],['718min',47,0],['719min',47,0],['720min',47,0],['721min',47,0],['722min',47,0],['723min',47,0],['724min',46,0],['725min',46,0],['726min',46,0],['727min',46,0],['728min',46,0],['729min',46,0],['730min',46,0],['731min',46,0],['732min',45,0],['733min',45,0],['734min',45,0],['735min',45,0],['736min',45,0],['737min',45,0],['738min',45,0],['739min',44,0],['740min',44,0],['741min',44,0],['742min',44,0],['743min',44,0],['744min',44,0],['745min',43,0],['746min',43,0],['747min',43,0],['748min',43,0],['749min',43,0],['750min',43,0],['751min',43,0],['752min',43,0],['753min',42,0],['754min',42,0],['755min',42,0],['756min',42,0],['757min',42,0],['758min',42,0],['759min',41,0],['760min',41,0],['761min',41,0],['762min',41,0],['763min',41,0],['764min',41,0],['765min',41,0],['766min',40,0],['767min',40,0],['768min',40,0],['769min',40,0],['770min',40,0],['771min',40,0],['772min',39,0],['773min',39,0],['774min',39,0],['775min',39,0],['776min',39,0],['777min',39,0],['778min',39,0],['779min',39,0],['780min',38,0],['781min',38,0],['782min',38,0],['783min',38,0],['784min',38,0],['785min',38,0],['786min',37,0],['787min',37,0],['788min',37,0],['789min',37,0],['790min',37,0],['791min',37,0],['792min',37,0],['793min',36,0],['794min',36,0],['795min',36,0],['796min',36,0],['797min',36,0],['798min',36,0],['799min',35,0],['800min',35,0],['801min',35,0],['802min',35,0],['803min',35,0],['804min',35,0],['805min',35,0],['806min',34,0],['807min',34,0],['808min',34,0],['809min',34,0],['810min',34,0],['811min',34,0],['812min',34,0],['813min',33,0],['814min',33,0],['815min',33,0],['816min',33,0],['817min',33,0],['818min',33,0],['819min',32,0],['820min',32,0],['821min',32,0],['822min',32,0],['823min',32,0],['824min',32,0],['825min',31,0],['826min',31,0],['827min',31,0],['828min',31,0],['829min',31,0],['830min',31,0],['831min',31,0],['832min',30,0],['833min',30,0],['834min',30,0],['835min',30,0],['836min',30,0],['837min',30,0],['838min',30,0],['839min',29,0],['840min',29,0],['841min',29,0],['842min',29,0],['843min',29,0],['844min',29,0],['845min',28,0],['846min',28,0],['847min',28,0],['848min',28,0],['849min',28,0],['850min',28,0],['851min',28,0],['852min',27,0],['853min',27,0],['854min',27,0],['855min',27,0],['856min',27,0],['857min',27,0],['858min',26,0],['859min',26,0],['860min',26,0],['861min',26,0],['862min',26,0],['863min',26,0],['864min',25,0],['865min',25,0],['866min',25,0],['867min',25,0],['868min',25,0],['869min',25,0],['870min',24,0],['871min',24,0],['872min',24,0],['873min',24,0],['874min',24,0],['875min',24,0],['876min',23,0],['877min',23,0],['878min',23,0],['879min',23,0],['880min',23,0],['881min',23,0],['882min',23,0],['883min',22,0],['884min',22,0],['885min',22,0],['886min',22,0],['887min',22,0],['888min',22,0],['889min',21,0],['890min',21,0],['891min',21,0],['892min',21,0],['893min',21,0],['894min',21,0],['895min',20,0],['896min',20,0],['897min',20,0],['898min',20,0],['899min',20,0],['900min',20,0],['901min',19,0],['902min',19,0],['903min',19,0],['904min',19,0],['905min',19,0],['906min',19,0],['907min',18,0],['908min',18,0],['909min',18,0],['910min',18,0],['911min',18,0],['912min',18,0],['913min',17,0],['914min',17,0],['915min',17,0],['916min',17,0],['917min',17,0],['918min',16,0],['919min',16,0],['920min',16,0],['921min',16,0],['922min',16,0],['923min',16,0],['924min',16,0],['925min',15,0],['926min',15,0],['927min',15,0],['928min',15,0],['929min',15,0],['930min',14,0],['931min',14,0],['932min',14,0],['933min',14,0],['934min',14,0],['935min',13,0],['936min',13,0],['937min',13,0],['938min',13,0],['939min',13,0],['940min',12,0],['941min',12,0],['942min',12,0],['943min',12,0],['944min',12,0],['945min',12,0],['946min',11,0],['947min',11,0],['948min',11,0],['949min',11,0],['950min',11,0],['951min',11,0],['952min',11,0],['953min',10,0],['954min',10,0],['955min',10,0],['956min',10,0],['957min',10,0],['958min',10,0],['959min',9,0],['960min',9,0],['961min',9,0],['962min',9,0],['963min',9,0],['964min',9,0],['965min',9,0],['966min',8,0],['967min',8,0],['968min',8,0],['969min',8,0],['970min',8,0],['971min',7,0],['972min',7,0],['973min',7,0],['974min',7,0],['975min',7,0],['976min',7,0],['977min',7,0],['978min',7,0],['979min',6,0],['980min',6,0],['981min',6,0],['982min',6,0],['983min',6,0],['984min',5,0],['985min',5,0],['986min',5,0],['987min',5,0],['988min',4,0],['989min',4,0],['990min',4,0],['991min',3,0],['992min',3,0],['993min',3,0],['994min',3,0],['995min',2,0],['996min',2,0],['997min',2,0],['998min',2,0],['999min',1,0]]"];
    chart_locations = ["charging_chart","discharging_chart"];


    for (a=0;a<chart_types.length;a++)
        {
            chart_type = chart_types[a];
            chart_data = chart_datas[a];

            chart_location = chart_locations[a];
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}); 

            setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    if (chart_type == "battery")
                            {
                                console.log("battery");
                        
                                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_data);
                                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chart_location));
                                var options = { bar: {groupWidth: "95%"} };
                                chart.draw(data,options);
                            }   
                }, 3000);
            
        }


}
```

I get the following error message in my browser console:

Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array.

If I use console.log to output the array, it is displayed as an array so I don't understand why Google Charts would not accept it.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, the data is defined as a string...

```
chart_datas = ["[['timing','charge'],['1min',1],['2min',1],['3min',1], ... ,['999min',1,0]]"];
```

just simply define as an array...

```
chart_datas = [[['timing','charge'],['1min',1],['2min',1],['3min',1], ... ,['999min',1,0]]];
```

note: don't recommend using `setTimeout` to wait for google charts to load,
this will not ensure google has finished loading every time.
although 5 seconds is probably too long.

but google's load statement returns a promise you can use to know when the load statement has completed...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function() {
  if (chart_type == "battery") {
    console.log("battery");

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chart_location));
    var options = { bar: {groupWidth: "95%"} };
    chart.draw(data,options);
  }   
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! You solved two problems in once. I simply removed the " from the php side and it worked. You also solved the loading issue, 3 seconds was a bet, it was working most of the time but now I have a better solution too! Thanks a lot.